# Make extern variable can't be accessed in specific files

Tags: c++, c++11, extern

So I have:

**foo.h**

```cpp
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

extern int bar;

void change_bar_value(const int& value);

#endif
```

**foo.cpp**

```cpp
#include "foo.h"

int bar = 10;

void change_bar_value(const int& value)
{
    bar = value;
}
```

and **main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
    bar = 20;
    change_bar_value(20);
}
```

So I want that you can't direcly change `bar` in `main.cpp`, but you can call a function that changes the value of `bar`. So how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Don't make it `extern`" is the obvious answer, and the generally preferrable solution.

If you desparately want something is globally readable but not writeable, alias it with a const reference.
(And don't pass primitives by const reference - it is a pointless pessimization.)

foo.h:

```
extern const int& bar;
void change_bar_value(int value);
```

foo.cpp:

```
static int local_bar;
const int& bar = local_bar;

void change_bar_value(int value)
{
    local_bar = value;
}
```